# PyTorch Lightning - LightningModule for ModuleList / ModuleDict?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

PyTorch has `ModuleList` and `ModuleDict`. How do I create equivalents in PyTorch Lightning to get all the nice properties of `LightningModule`s?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you are wanting to have lists or dicts of `LightningModule`s, you should be able to use PyTorch's `ModuleList` and `ModuleDict` since `LightningModule` is a subclass of `nn.Module`.

Comment: I would like a `LightningModuleList` and a `LightningModuleDict`

Comment: I do not want a `ModuleList` of `LightningModule`s (or a `ModuleDict` of `LightningModule`s)

Comment: What is the end objective? Can you clarify what unique properties of `LightningModule`s you need the list or dict of models to have?

Comment: The device management. How to distribute the computation across the hardware

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the `ModuleDict`/`ModuleList` in the `LightningModule` and since the both ModuleDict and ModuleList inherits from `torch.nn.Module` so it will work just like that without you needing to do anything.